# github not importing on windows using heroku

Tags: github, heroku

So I am trying to import my git file from heroku to have as a back up code source to save our most recent succesful updates.  I literally copied the heroku url as the old repository clone url, I left the page and it told me that no source repositories are found on heroku. what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: It's unclear. What does "*import my git file from heroku*" mean? Are you cloning your repo from Heroku..? Are you trying to import a Heroku project into another Heroku project? And what page is "*left the page*"? Please [edit] to clarify your problem.

Comment: I have a heroku url that i am trying to import with  github and github is telling me I have no source repositories

Comment: This question was duplicated and clarified here: ["No source repositories were detected at(my app). Please check the URL and try again."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550438/no-source-repositories-were-detected-atmy-app-please-check-the-url-and-try-a). It would have been better to just [edit] the existing post instead of posting duplicates of it.