# "No source repositories were detected at(my app). Please check the URL and try again."

Tags: github, heroku

I have a URL for my Heroku app here: https://damp-sands-09329.herokuapp.com/.

When I go to https://github.com/new/import, I am told to enter "Your old repository’s clone URL" and I entered the site URL and it said to me

> No source repositories were detected at
>   https://damp-sands-09329.herokuapp.com/. Please check the URL and try
>   again.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

If your source repository is on GitHub, make sure its visibility is set to public and not private.

Answer (score 0):

Github is correct, what you provided is not a valid Git repository URL.

The Heroku site or web URL (of the form https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/) is where your website is *deployed*, but that's not where the source codes are *stored*.

What you want is the Heroku Git URL. You can get this in 2 ways:

1. From the Heroku dashboard

   Login into your Heroku dashboard (https://dashboard.heroku.com), go to your app, then go to **Settings**, then scroll to the **Info** section. It's the one specified as the **Heroku Git URL** and is of the form https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxx.git.

   [image]
2. From the Heroku CLI

   If you have Heroku CLI installed, you can use the [`apps:info`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps-info) command to get the Git URL.

   ```
   $ heroku apps:info app-name
   === app-name
   ...
   Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
   ...
   Web URL:        https://app-name.herokuapp.com/
   ```

   Notice that it shows the Git URL and the Web URL. Github wants the Git URL.